# Can jQuery's filter be used such that it stops searching when the first element is found?

Tags: jquery, filter

The following element is found according to its index.

```
var listDiv = $( "div[class*='item-title']" ).filter(function( index ) {
                    return index === curActiveItem
                  });
```

In this case, it appears that jQuery would continue to search the selected elements as having the index passed into the filter.

Is there a way to use ":first" with this example, or is there a more efficient way to filter the items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the index then you can get the element at that index with [**`.eq`**](https://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
var listDiv = $( "div[class*='item-title']" ).eq(curActiveItem);
```

---

> Can jQuery's filter be used so that it stops searching when the first element is found?

No. But you can do that with [**`.each`**](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
var listDiv = $();
$( "div[class*='item-title']" ).each(function() {
   if (someCondition) {
     listDiv = $(this);
     return false;
   }
});
```

Or use [**`Array#some`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
$($( "div[class*='item-title']" ).get().some(function(element) {
   return someCondition;
}));
```