# jQuery .filter(): exit before the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I have this code:

```
var image_match = $('#my_id image').filter(function(i, el) {
    return  el.attributes.x.value == x_image;
});
```

`$('#my_id image')` gives a very long array (some thousands) but luckily I know how many elements will pass the test (generally just one) so I could stop the 'loop' as soon as it finds the element(s). The problem is I don't know how to do (or if it's possible).

This is to increase the efficiency, so I'm looking for an efficient solution.

Maybe something like this, but is it efficient?

```
var target_number=3;//or whatever
var image_match = $('#my_id image').filter(function(i, el) {
    var counter=0;
    if (el.attributes.x.value == x_image) {
        counter+=1;
    };
    if (counter==target_number) {
        return  el.attributes.x.value == x_image;
        break;//return (false);//exit
    }
    return  el.attributes.x.value == x_image;
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find or findIndex?

Comment: exact duplicate, but, this may be a better question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264318/can-jquerys-filter-be-used-such-that-it-stops-searching-when-the-first-element/33264354#33264354

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't break out of a `filter()` loop as it's designed to apply its logic to all elements.

If you want to exit a loop early, I'd suggest changing your logic to use `each()`. Then you can `return false;` to exit the loop:

```
var target_number = 3, matches = [];

$('#my_id image').each(function(i, el) {
  if (el.attributes.x.value == x) {
    matches.push($(this));

    if (matches.length == target_number)
      return false;
  }
});
```

`matches` will now be roughly equivalent to the content of your `image_match` variable, except it will be an array instead of a jQuery object.

Alternatively you can use `map()` to directly build an array which contains only the values required:

```
let matches = $('#my_id image').map((i, el) => el.attributes.x.value === x ? $(el) : null).get();
```